# How can I view .mat file in VS Code?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code

I want to open a Matlab's .mat file in my VS Code without having Matlab environment installed in my machine. However, I couldn't find any extensions to do so.
My system is macOS.
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: `.mat` files are binary save files, not code.  You can e.g. load them with python, but you can not "see" them, not in visual-studio neither in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is, `.mat` files are saved variables in Matlab and I want to view them as tables like Excel or SQL. Are there any extensions able to do so?

Comment: You may need to read what a binary file is. No, the info is not stored in human readable format, its compressed binary data. Files read by excel are in human readable formats, not binary. My original comment was meant to clarify this. You can however choose a programming language that you like and that can read `.mat` files (e.g. python) and write code that loads this data and then saves it in a different format that is human readable. That is various steps.

Comment: Sure, of course, I know the difference between binary and text files. I am also capable of reading `.mat` files with Python or C++ programming languages. Nevertheless, when I'm developing my programs in VS Code, it's not so convenient to open my `.mat` data files with another application or by a Python script. It would be appreciated if I could view the data directly in my VS Code window, possibly with the help of a suitable extension.

Comment: Yeah, but to "view" a file is to read it. And if its binary, then it's data, not something readable with a text editor (vsc is essentially a text editor). I can repeat myself on why this does not make sense in principle, but that would just be repeating myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the .mat file using scipy and then visualize it using the Data Viewer. You would first need to install the Python and Jupyter extensions for VSCode.

Here is a very basic sample example:

```python
from   scipy.io   import  loadmat
import numpy      as      np
matrixVar = loadmat( "someMatrix.mat" )

# Do whatever data manipulation you need here
# Let's do a simple transpose for the sake of the example.
mainpulatedData = np.transpose(matrixVar)

# Do more stuff here if needed
# ...
print( 'Done processing' )
```

To open the Data Viewer, place a breakpoint after the line where your data is loaded and processed, then run Python in Debug mode. In the right hand-side, right-click on the variable of interest (`mainpulatedData` in this example) and choose `View Value in Data Viewer`.

[This is how you access the Data Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KafMy.png).

[Here is an example of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBmd8.png).

I am not sure why some members of the community were arguing a moot point over semantics and definitions with you earlier, but to each their own I guess.

Best of luck!